# Need Help Undefined Offset Error

Tags: php, wordpress

was wondering if anyone could help me out. I have been looking all over the place for an answer and can't seem to find one.

I am kind of a novice at PHP and i am pretty familiar with WordPress. I added three new layouts to the default twentyeleven theme. The way I envisioned this working was if someone selected a particular layout an extra sidebar would appear. So I came up with the following (yeah i know it probably isn't correct but I did it myself and it works...lol)

```
            $options = themeawesome_get_theme_options();
            $classes = $options['three-column' || 'three-column-left' || 'three-column-right'];
            if ( 'content' != $classes ) {
            get_sidebar('alt');
            }
```

like said it works great and shows the alt sidebar if any of those choices are selected in the theme options panel.

Only thing is I get the following error:

> Undefined offset: 1 on line 8

line 8 being the 2nd line of code above.

Can anyone help me remove this error. Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use multiple indexes in an array, as you're attempting to do with:

```
$classes = $options['three-column' || 'three-column-left' || 'three-column-right'];
```

I'm not exactly sure what goal you're trying to achieve, so I have multiple answers as to how to fix it.

First, declare the list of available themes:

```
$themes = array('three-column', 'three-column-left', 'three-column-right');
```

If you want an array, `$classes`, with each class, try:

```
$classes = array();
foreach ($themes as $theme) {
    if (isset($options[$theme])) {
        $classes = $options[$theme]; 
    }
}
```

If you want to get the "first theme available", try:

```
$classes = '';
foreach ($themes as $theme) {
    if (isset($options[$theme])) {
        $classes = $options[$theme];
        break;
    }
}
```

Because you're following if-statement (`if ('content' != $classes)`) is checking for a single string, the second of my examples may suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much, you were correct, your second answer worked perfectly. What i was trying to accomplish was if a particular layout was chosen in the theme options panel then the alt sidebar would show along with the regular sidebar. Again thank you very much.